# Lua MoveMouse While Pressed G button

Tags: events, lua, logitech-gaming-software

I have a little question for gurus. Please help me for this. I'm so new at Lua coding. Please forgive me maybe it's so easy but i didn't find any solution for this yet.

I need to move mouse cursor while press G button of mouse. I'm using logitech G502 and i wrote a script like this for mouse;

[image]

It's working for once time. But i want to make it repeatly while pressing 8th button of mouse. Can any have idea for this?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? do you mean the function runs a single time on each button press, and you would like it to run until the button is released?

Comment: I need repeat movement while pressed button down.

Answer (score 1):

`OnEvent` will only fire once on key press and once on key release, This is why you are not seeing the code loop as you would like it to.

You need to initiate a loop in your `OnEvent` function. Based on the documentation I found you can use the `IsMouseButtonPressed` function as your loop condition.

```
function OnEvent(event, arg, mouse)
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 8 then
        while IsMouseButtonPressed(8) do -- This will check if the key is still pressed every loop
            MoveMouseRelative(0,20)
            MoveMouseRelative(0,20)
            MoveMouseRelative(0,20)
            sleep(50)
        end
    elseif event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_RELEASED" and arg == 8 then
        i_pressed = notok
        Sleep(50)
    end

    OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %d, press = %s\n", event, arg, i_pressed)
    MoveMouseDown()
end
```

I have found comments that state `IsMouseButtonPressed` does not work for buttons 6 or higher, it maybe necessary to change the button to one that is 1-5 rather then 8.